# Calculation over multiple columns with similar suffix

Tags: python, dataframe, function, for-loop, iteration

The example dataframe looks like this:

`d = {'id': [1, 2],'year': [1999, 2020],'cat_up': [0, 15], 'cat_down': [2, 60],'dog_up': [1, 11], 'dog_down': [2, 12],'fish_up': [12, 11], 'fish_down': [22, 12]}`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

```
   id  year  cat_up  cat_down  dog_up  dog_down  fish_up  fish_down
0   1  1999       0         2       1         2       12         22
1   2  2020      15        60      11        12       11         12
```

And the real dataframe has about another 60 more columns, all have _up or _down suffix.

I want to add new _res columns by divide each _up / _down, for example:

```
df['cat_res'] = df['cat_up']/df['cat_down']
df['dog_res'] = df['dog_up']/df['dog_down']
...
```

I tried to use for loop, and the one below is not right:

```
up_cols = [col for col in df.columns if '_up' in col]
down_cols  = [col for col in df.columns if '_down' in col]
 
for up, down in enumerate(up_cols, down_cols):
    df[column + '_res'] =  up_cols/ down_cols
```

Can anyone tell me how to do the calculation and iterate over columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be careful about your columns, as your dataframe might have columns with the `_up` suffix not related to any other column with `_down` suffix, you can make use of sets.

```
up_cols = [col[:-3] for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_up")]
down_cols = [col[:-5] for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_down")]

# Using sets intersection to address the case when there is a X_up but no X_down
for col in set(up_cols)&set(down_cols): 
    df[col+"_res"] = df[col+"_up"]/df[col+"_down"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for up, down in zip(up_cols, down_cols):
    df[up.replace("_up", "_res")] = df[up]/df[down]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.